# Independent program

Tags: android, installation-package

I need to install a program on the Droid.  I can get it onto the memory chip.  I can't get the droid to find it.  TIA.

Comment: This does not seem like a programmer question, but a usage question, and as such would be better to ask on superuser.com, for example.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are trying to say is that you have an apk file on your SD card you are trying to install onto your phone.  You need to use a file browser like Astro File Manager to browse your SD card and install the app.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you are trying to install an APK which is in your SD card.
There's no need to use a file manager, just open the Browser and enter the URL

```
file:///sdcard/MyApp.apk
```

you will be prompted to accept the installation of the package.

Answer (score 0):

To install the apk you will also need to allow installations from Unknown Sources, located in Settings --> Applications.